# Secure a PDF document on a future date

Tags: security, pdf, javascript, adobe-acrobat

I'd like to "secure" a PDF document on some future date (specified by me). By "secure" I mean either of the following:

1. the document becomes encrypted with a password (and cannot be open without one)
2. the document content is self-destructed / digitally shredded

I have Acrobat Pro, which allows me to set a document password, but not on a specified future date. I'm wondering if there's a way to allow such protection to be effective after a certain delay.

I've seen some methods that uses Javascript. But I don't know how robust such methods are on non-Adobe viewers.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I think for that you will need a DRM (Digital Rights Management) system. Adobe has one, part of the LiveCycle product family (now probably renamed); FileOpen by FileOpen might be worthwhile to look at.

Comment: @MaxWyss Thanks for the suggestion. Are you aware of any open source or free alternatives? I'm not seeking commercial-grade encryption products, and LiveCycle and FileOpen aren't exactly cheap to use.

Comment: Not that I am aware of. As always when it comes to security-related issues, it is up to you to decide how much the protection is worth for you.